# Can I connect a 1A device to a USB 3 port?

Tags: arduino, led, current, usb, ws2812b

All,

If I  were to connect 16 WS2182b LEDs in series (16*0.06=0.96A) and an Arduino to a USB 3 port on my PC (0.9A max I think), would my PC/USB controller get fried or would the LEDs just run dimmer?

Would this be safe to do this or would I need to use a separate power supply for the LEDs?

Thanks

Comment: Running the LEDs in series requires higher *voltage*, not higher current.

Comment: You're actually connecting the WS2182B LEDs in parallel, not in series, but you've calculated for parallel connection so that's OK.

Comment: Regardless of all that, if the load is less than what the power supply can provide then it will work fine, and if the load is more than what it can provide, it most likely won't work at all; the voltage will fall and it's likely the Arduino won't be able to run reliably on the lower voltage. Here, you're close enough to the rating that I suspect it will be fine, as long as the arduino doesn't consume too much current; I don't know how much power they use. (and it'd depend on your code anyway)

Comment: The Intel USB controllers at least have overcurrent sensing and will cut power if they detect too much current draw (you get a nice popup in windows telling you as well).  In this case you are drawing too much current, but probably not enough that the overcurrent will engage.  My guess is it will work (at least on an Intel system) but it isn't ideal.

Comment: Good point about it being parallel, not series. I plan to connect it to an external power supply because I haven't included the power draw of the Arduino itself and I'm also not using an Intel controller, however I believe the AMD controllers also have protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1310631/742827) and [this manual](https://www.cypress.com/file/134171/download):

> To start, the power delivery is defined in "units of load". For USB
> 2.0 one unit is 100 mA, and for USB 3.x one unit is 150 mA.

> ...

> The requirements for power delivery from a normal USB port should not
> be confused with requirements for USB DEVICES: USB devices should NOT
> take more than one unit of load until host completes the device
> enumeration.

> ...

> Before a device is configured, it must not use more than 100 mA, defined as one unit load in the USB specification, of power for low, full, or high-speed devices.

While I think this actually will likely work with your USB3.0 port as most motherboards will tolerate maximum current without any negotiation, still this isn't really a good idea. You mess up with USB specs and weird things could happen. For example if somebody will attach it to a USB 1/2 port which can handle 500mA maximum only and your device will start drawing 900mA+ without even negotiating this is possible at all.

That is why usually high power (> 100mA) USB devices will have some sort of IC which can negotiate power capabilities of the host or DCP (dedicated charge port, i.e. USB wall adapter).

EDIT: Assuming you have Arduino, which will have a some sort of USB-UART bridge this should already negotiate & enumerate USB device. But still it has some drawbacks. It's not a USB 3.0 IC, and enumeration will take some time.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Didn't know about the units stuff, that's good to know.